# What are the arguments of the mathematicians who objected against the ontological proof Gödel offered?

Tags: soft-question, proof-explanation, book-recommendation, math-history, philosophy

**Q:**

> What are the arguments of the mathematicians who objected against the [ontological argument/proof Gödel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof) offered?

$$
\begin{array}{rl} \text{Ax. 1.} & \left\{P(\varphi) \wedge \Box \; \forall x[\varphi(x) \to \psi(x)]\right\} \to P(\psi) \\ \text{Ax. 2.} & P(\neg \varphi) \leftrightarrow \neg P(\varphi) \\ \text{Th. 1.} & P(\varphi) \to \Diamond \; \exists x[\varphi(x)] \\ \text{Df. 1.} & G(x) \iff \forall \varphi [P(\varphi) \to \varphi(x)] \\ \text{Ax. 3.} & P(G) \\ \text{Th. 2.} & \Diamond \; \exists x \; G(x) \\ \text{Df. 2.} & \varphi \text{ ess } x \iff \varphi(x) \wedge \forall \psi \left\{\psi(x) \to \Box \; \forall y[\varphi(y) \to \psi(y)]\right\} \\ \text{Ax. 4.} & P(\varphi) \to \Box \; P(\varphi) \\ \text{Th. 3.} & G(x) \to G \text{ ess } x \\ \text{Df. 3.} & E(x) \iff \forall \varphi[\varphi \text{ ess } x \to \Box \; \exists y \; \varphi(y)] \\ \text{Ax. 5.} & P(E) \\ \text{Th. 4.} & \Box \; \exists x \; G(x) \end{array} $$

I want to learn. Because, Gödel's proof was checked on the computer. Well, How can mathematicians criticize, if Gödel's proof is controlled by the computer and known to be true?I cannot understand how an object that is external is mathematically proven. What did the computer actually confirm?

I want to know the problems in Gödel's proof.

Any book or link you recommend , or answer will satisfy me.

Comment: You can start with a dedicated book regrding the proof : Melvin Fitting, [Types, Tableaus, and Gödel’s God](https://books.google.it/books?id=9XWB7OywK1oC&pg=PR3), Kluwer (2002).

Comment: Checked means "formally correct", i.e. no logical errors found. True means, formally correct **and** derived from *true* axioms: this last point is the crux of the matter, and computers cannot do this (up to now).

Comment: I want to know something I don't know. Because I don't know and want to know. Why downvote, I can not understand..

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much for the book.

Comment: Personal (and not answering your question): everything we know about God (including existence) is something that is revealed by God Himself.

Comment: There is a also a summary of the situation on the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, at https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-arguments/#GodOntArg .  The general issue of ontological arguments is philosophical, rather than mathematical.

Comment: @Beginner I hope you do not claim that this means that a computer proved that God exists !

Answer (score 6):

The proof is of course, sound. But to claim that this argument proves that God as we understand exists, you also need to argue that the axioms really hold in the real world, which I believe would be extremely hard.

Edit : Another criticism comes from the fact that the same axioms can be used to prove that there must be infinitely many semi-gods.

Comment: "Semi-god" - nice! (+1 for that)

Comment: If you happen to know the details of the proof : Can we prove this way also that Santa Claus exists ? I only ask because I do not understand how Goedel wanted to link God with mathematics.

Comment: I do not know every detail of the proof, but basically it says that there are beings missing almost none of the "good" properties. I also don't think Gödel was really trying to prove that the God exists and as far as I remember, he only trying to formalize the ontological proof.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. So he did not claim that he actually proved God's existence mathematically ?

Comment: No, he definitely did not.